# .net core get user in ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I am trying to access the current user (i.e. ClaimsPrincipal from identity) in a custom ValidationAttribute, and I haven't figured out how I could do that.

```
public class UniqueTitleValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      // var user = ?
    }
}
```

I know that I could access the user from a HttpContext (but I don't know how to get to the latter).

The main problem is that I don't have access to the User. When I use a custom ValidatorAttribute on a property, when the property gets constructed the User (or also HttpContext) is null. Meaning that I can't e.g. give the User to the Validator's constructor. That's why I'm wondering how the Validator could be made to know something about the User (and/or its claims). If I can access any of e.g. HttpContext or User inside the validator, I can get to all the other runtime information as well. Is my question understandable?

Comment: `sub` will give u the user id if u just want userId.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`ValidationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext?view=netcore-2.1) has its own [`GetService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.getservice?view=netcore-2.1) method, which is preconfigured to use the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection container, [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-2.1), when resolving services. Here's an example:

```
public class UniqueTitleValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        ...
    }
}
```

To get to `HttpContext`, use [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which is resolved here using `GetService` as described above. You'll need to make sure you've registered this with DI, using e.g. [`AddHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpservicecollectionextensions.addhttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.1).