# Why is User.Identity.Name returning null in my ProfileValidator class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a web app using ASP.NET Core 7.0 with MVC, Identity, and Entity Framework. The project is a social media network for writers and allows users to have one account (PenUser) that is connected to multiple public-facing profiles (PenProfile) so that writers can post their work under different pen names or have both writer and publisher/literary agent profiles.

In general, the Identity aspects of the project seem to be working. I can create a PenUser and log in and out of the project. The controller (ProfileController) for the Profile pages (where you can create or view PenProfiles) uses [Authorize], and I am able to access the pages within it when logged in. ProfileController also inherits from a controller called AccessController that has a bunch of different functions for getting various things from Identity or the database. All of this seems fine.

However, I have created a class called ProfileValidator that has various validators for elements of the profile so that you can't create a profile with an invalid username or that uses a URL string for its address that is already taken. This is where I am running into issues as User.Identity.Name is always returning null.

Here's the relevant code with some parts taken out where they are not relevant to the question.

AccessController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Penfolio2.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account;
using Penfolio2.Data;
using Penfolio2.Models;

namespace Penfolio2.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccessController : Controller
    {
        public AccessController()
        {

        }

        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public string? GetUserName()
        {
            return User?.Identity?.Name;
        }

        protected string GetUserId()
        {
            return db.PenUsers.Where(i => i.NormalizedUserName == User.Identity.Name.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }

        protected bool UserHasProfile()
        {
            return db.PenProfiles.Any(i => i.UserId == GetUserId());
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Penfolio2.Data;
using Penfolio2.Models;

namespace Penfolio2.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ProfileController : AccessController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;

        public ProfileController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) : base()
        {
            this.environment = environment;
        }

        // GET: ProfileController/Create
        [Route("Profile/Create")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if (UserHasProfile())
            {
                ViewBag.HasProfile = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.HasProfile = "false";
            }

            return View();
        }

        // POST: ProfileController/Create
        [Route("Profile/Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateProfileViewModel model)
        {
            string userId = GetUserId();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Code for creating the profile

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileValidator

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Penfolio2.Data;
using Penfolio2.Models;
using Penfolio2.Controllers;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Penfolio2.Validation
{
    public class ProfileValidator
    {
        public class DisplayNameForCreateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                var profile = (CreateProfileViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
                List<IdentityError> errors = new List<IdentityError>();
                DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options = new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>();
                ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
                AccessController ac = new AccessController();
                string? username = ac.GetUserName();
                PenUser user;

                if (profile == null)
                {
                    errors.Add(new IdentityError()
                    {
                        Description = "Profile fields must be completed."
                    });
                }
                else if (username == null)
                {
                    errors.Add(new IdentityError()
                    {
                        Description = "Profiles can only be created by registered users. If you have an account, please log in."
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    //actual error checks go here, but the code is not reaching this point because username is always null
                }

                string errorString = "";

                foreach (IdentityError error in errors)
                {
                    errorString += error.Description + " ";
                }

                return errors.Count == 0 ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(errorString);
            }
        }
```

ViewModels

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Penfolio2.Validation;

namespace Penfolio2.Models
{
    public class CreateProfileViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
        [ProfileValidator.DisplayNameForCreate]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        //there are other fields, but they are not important for the sake of this question
    }
}
```

In case anyone is curious, profile creation works perfectly when `[ProfileValidator.DisplayNameForCreate]` is commented out in ViewModels. UserHasProfile() is also working correctly in ProfileController. The problem is very clearly something with ProfileValidator specifically, but nothing I have done so far has made any difference.

Comment: [get user in ValidationAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030838/net-core-get-user-in-validationattribute)